# policy for same answer for difference question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I wrote an answer to [Load JQuery into any page using Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853692/load-jquery-into-any-page-using-firebug/30553332#30553332)

And also wrote the same answer for [Running jQuery call in Firebug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851665/running-jquery-call-in-firebug-console/30553325#30553325)

But I received this alert:

> " Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one
>   good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as
>   duplicates. –  bluefeet♦ 2 days ago "

But I thinks this is not correction policy because maybe two different questions need the same answer.

For example, About these questions:

- `2 + 4 = ?`
- `2 * 3 = ?`

For both, answer is 6, but they are not duplicate questions.

Answer (score 9):

Yes the final answer is 6 to both but the entire solution on **how** you arrived at the answer is different.  Addition and multiplication are 2 different functions that are derived differently.

Instead of putting a copy and paste duplicate answer to both questions, you should craft your answer to fit each question.  Explain why the answer is 6 and how you arrive at the answer.

If you do that, then your answers won't be duplicates.

But if the exact method with the same exact explanation is necessary to solve both questions, then they are likely duplicate questions.